# How to push a local repository to a branch of another repository on Github

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to add a project that is only stored on my local machine to a branch of an existing project on Github.

For example add:

```bash
local-project
```

to the Github repo:

```bash
https://github.com/myusername/my-project/local-branch.git
```

Can this be done or should the local repo first be pushed to it's own Github repo?

**Additional info:**
Here is some extra info as per the comments I have received so far. So basically I have a Github repo (my-project) that contains a Next.js project that is currently in production. I would like to update this project to a completely different language (REACT NATIVE), that is currently still in development. The React Native version I have been working on is only locally on my computer, as I cloned a repo and haven't pushed it to Github yet. My ultimate goal is to have the React Native version as a branch (local-branch) in the (my-project) Github repo. Then when the local-branch is ready for production I can simply merge it to main.

Comment: You can't "push a repository". You can only push a branch.

Comment: Since your terminology seems a bit confused, as said, it would be good to know, why do you want to do this, what is your ultimate goal? Why should this be a branch in a repository, instead of an independent repository?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @hyde, I will update the questions now to give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you can push a branch, not repository.

Now:

```bash
git remote add remote-repo <remote-repo-url>
git push remote-repo local-branch:<remote-new-branch-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

> as I cloned a repo and haven't pushed it to Github yet

Assuming that you cloned the original Next.js project and created a new branch to work on the React Native version, all you have to do is `git push origin <branch>` to push your branch to the github repo. You don't need to create a remote in your local repo as I explained in my original answer below because `git clone` already creates one for you.

### Original answer

First to clarify some terminology, you can't "push a local repository".  Instead, you can only push commits from your local repo to a remote repo. A branch gives us a shortcut for how to refer to a specific sequence of commits.

To do this, first you need to create a remote:

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

For example

```
git remote add my-remote https://github.com/myusername/my-project/local-branch.git
```

By default, git will create a remote named `origin` when you `git clone` another repo.

Once you have a remote, you can push your branch:

```
git push my-remote my-branch
```

While you can do this with any branch and any repo, it usually only makes sense if the two repositories have a common history, such as when you clone a github repo locally or if you create a new repo locally and want to push a branch to an new, empty repo on github.

Comment: Hey @Code-Apprentice, thanks you for the answer. Sorry for the confusion with the terminology I have updated my question. Please note, the local-project does not belong to a Github repo, it is just a folder on my local computer.

Comment: More precisely, you push *commits*, using a branch name to help yourself and Git find the commits.

Comment: @herbie Another clarification of terminology: It doesn't make sense to say "`local-project` does not belong to a github repo" because your local project doesn't belong to anything. It is itself a repo. You add remotes to one repo to connect it to another repo. In fact, the folder on your local computer is that repo. It contains a subfolder named `.git` which contains the data about the repo. It's not hard to imagine that a server owned by GitHub has a folder exactly like your local folder.

Comment: @herbie To learn more, I suggest reading [Chapter 2 - Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) from Git Pro. Particularly the section on remotes will help clarify these details for you.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the suggestion. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @herbie See my updated answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with clear definitions.  In particular:

- A *Git repository* is, at its heart, a collection of commits—a database of what Git calls *commit objects*, plus supporting objects that make the commits actually useful (make them contain files)—along with a secondary database to help you and Git *find* the commits.
- This in turn means that Git is all about *commits*.  It's not about files!  Commits *contain* files, which is why *we* use commits.  But Git isn't all that concerned with the files, at least when taking a high level view.  And, it's not really about *branches* either, but we organize and—most importantly—*find* the commits via branch names, which is how branches enter the picture.

Git doesn't really have a concept of a *project*.  That concept is up to you to define.  Git has the concept of a *repository*, and the repository is made up of commits and other objects.  So if you have an existing repository, you have an existing pile of commits (along with their other objects).

In your update, you say:

> I would like to update this project to a completely different language (REACT NATIVE), that is currently still in development.

You're still talking about a "project".  Git doesn't have those, so you must map your own concept of "project" onto the things Git has: repositories that contain commits.

> The React Native version I have been working on is only locally on my computer, as I cloned a repo[sitory] ...

Here, you mention another—apparently *different*—*repository*.  This is something Git understands.  You now seem to have at least three repositories:

- one on GitHub;
- a different one you cloned from somewhere (somewhere else on GitHub?); and
- a third one that's closely related to the second one.

> and haven't pushed it to Github yet.

The pronoun "it" here seems to refer to your third repository.  But you do not—*can* not—push a *repository*.  You push some set of commits (and their supporting objects), which *exist within* a repository, and which you and Git find using branch names and other names.

It's now time to talk a bit more about repositories, commits, and *clones*.

#### The repository as a pair of databases

Databases take many forms, but the two that make up the bulk of any Git repository are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  A key-value database (see more at the Wikipedia link) takes, as its input, a *key*, and uses that to retrieve a *value*.

For a commit object, the key is the commit's name.  The "name" of a commit is a big, ugly, random-looking (but not actually random) *hash ID* such as [`4af7188bc97f70277d0f10d56d5373022b1fa385`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4af7188bc97f70277d0f10d56d5373022b1fa385).  These hash IDs are particularly magical, because:

- they are *unique:* no two different commits ever have the same hash ID;
- every Git system everywhere in the universe computes them the same way, so that even if you haven't made a commit yet, once you make it and it gets some hash ID, every Git system in the universe will agree that, yep, *that* commit you just made, just now, deserves and gets *that hash ID* and no other commit can ever have it now that you've taken it.

This deep magic is related in various ways to cryptography, and the way Git [ab]uses it literally can't work forever.  The sheer size of the hash ID space is meant to make sure it works long enough that nobody cares.  But all you really need to know is that the hash ID—which Git formally calls an *object ID* or OID—is the "true name" of the commit.  Git literally *needs* this hash ID to find the commit in its big database of all of its objects.

If this were the only database Git had, we'd all have to memorize these random-looking hash IDs.  This would be very bad, because humans are *bad* at these things.  So Git has a *second* database.  This second database is also a simple key-value store, but the keys in it are things like branch and tag names, which are human-readable and make sense to humans: names like `main` or `master`, `develop`, and so on.  Git will store the hash ID of the *latest* commit in some branch under the branch name, in this second database.

That means all *you* have to remember is the branch name you're using.  You say "get me the latest `main` commit" or "get me the latest `dev` commit", and Git fishes out the hash ID from the *names* database and then uses that to fish the commit out of the big all-objects database.

In other words, you don't need to memorize hash IDs.  You *do* still need to know that the commits are *numbered*, using these funny-weird [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) OID or hash ID thingies, and that there's one per commit.  But you don't have to memorize any of them: just run `git log`, for instance, and Git itself will *show* them to you, and you can use your mouse to cut-and-paste a hash ID if you need one (eventually, you will need one, now and then—maybe very rarely, maybe once a week or twice a day or something, but someday, probably).

#### What to know about a commit

Besides being numbered like this, a commit:

- Is completely read-only.  This is required for the numbering system to work, but it means that you literally cannot change anything about any commit, once you make it.  This isn't really a big deal because commits in Git normally hardly take any space at all.
- Stores two things:

  - Each commit has a *full snapshot of every file*.
  - Each commit has some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.

The first sub-bullet-point seems to contradict the claim that commits are normally pretty tiny.  If every commit holds *every file*, won't the repository database bloat up enormously?  And it would, except for some very clever Git tricks.  The number one trick is that the files *in* the commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only format (as objects in that big all-objects database, in fact) in which *duplicated file contents are de-duplicated*.

Since most commits mostly re-use most of their files from a previous commit, and such files are automatically *de-duplicated*, they take no space!  It's only the *changed* files that actually take any space.  Git later—not right away—compresses *those* as well; as long as they are normal text or programming-language contents, this usually works tremendously well.  (For *binary* files, though, it usually fails, which is why Git is ill-suited to storing most binary files.)

So this—the compressed and *de-duplicated* files as Git objects—is *how* Git stores every file in every commit without actually storing every file in every commit, and hence without having the repository grow obscenely fat.  You don't need to know this to use Git, you just need to know that every file *seems* to be stored, forever, in every commit.  That is, make a commit, and you can get all your files back, forever—or rather, for as long as you can *find* that commit.  You'll need its hash ID!  (Do you see why hash IDs are important, now?)

But I just said that you don't need to memorize hash IDs, and that's true.  So how does that work?  Well, let's look more closely at that metadata.  Every commit stores information about itself, and that information includes things like the name and email address of the person who *made* the commit, and some date-and-time stamps, and so on.  But there's a crucial bit of information in here for *Git itself:* **Every commit stores the hash ID of the commit that comes before it.**

More precisely, each commit has a *list* of previous commit hash IDs.  But this list is usually exactly one element long.  That one element, the one list entry, holds the *parent commit's* hash ID.  This means commits have parent/child relationships, with most commits having just a single parent (mother? father? pick whatever you like here, Git is gender-agnostic).

Because a commit is totally read-only, the *child* commit can remember its parent's "name" (hash ID), as the parent exists when we create the child.  But the parent *can't* remember its childrens' names, because its children—if there will be any—don't exist yet.  As soon as the child is born, it's cryogenically frozen, and can't learn its future childrens' names.

We say that the child *points to* its parent, and if we want, we can draw some commits this way.  Using single uppercase letters to stand in for real hash IDs, we'll call the *last* commit in the branch `H` (for Hash) and draw it like this:

```
            <-H
```

That arrow sticking out of `H` is how `H` uses its parent hash ID storage, in its metadata, to point to its parent.  We'll draw its parent in now, as the letter `G` since that comes before `H`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course `G` points backwards to *its* parent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

and as you can see, this makes an endless backwards-pointing chain *except* that history eventually runs out when we get back to the very first commit ever.  That *first* commit has *no* parent, like some sort of virgin birth but without even a mother, so that commit—let's call it `A`—just doesn't point backwards after all:

```
A--B--...--G--H
```

We can get lazy and stop drawing the arrows as arrows because we know they're part of the commit and can't be changed and therefore *must* point backwards.

#### Branch names find commits

The problem with the above is that you still have to memorize hash ID `H`, the *last* commit in the chain: the *tip* of the chain.  We've already seen, though, that a Git repository contains a second database of names, and that the *branch* names hold the hash ID of the last commit.  As with commits pointing to earlier commits, we say that the *branch name* points to the *tip commit*, and we draw that in like so:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch
```

To *add a new commit* to the branch, Git will simply write out the new commit with its full snapshot and metadata, acquiring the new unique hash ID in the process.  The hash ID will look random; we'll call it `I` here, the next letter after `H`.  Commit `I` will *point to* commit `H`, the way any commit has to point backwards to its parent:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch
         \
          I
```

and because new commit `I` *is* the new *tip* of the chain of commits, Git will now write `I`'s hash ID into the *branch name* in the database, so that the name now points to `I`:

```
...--G--H    branch
         \  ↙︎
          I
```

(the arrow I used here is kind of lame; this is why I get lazy about the arrows between commits).  We don't need `I` on a separate line after all: it makes more sense to draw this as:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- branch
```

Note that the arrow sticking out of a branch name *can and does move, all the time*.  This makes it very different from the rigid, backwards-pointing arrow sticking out of a commit, pointing to the commit's parent.  **Git simply *defines* the branch name as "this is the last commit".  That is, whatever hash ID is in the branch name, that's the last commit on the branch.**  So to change *which commit is the last commit*, you have Git stuff a new hash ID into the branch name.  This not only lets you add commits *to* the branch, but also lets you *remove* commits *from* the branch:

```
       H--I   ???
      /
...--G   <-- branch
```

If we have Git store `G`'s hash ID in the branch name, we've dropped commits `H` and `I` from the branch.  They're still *in the repository*, but now you need to know their hash IDs!  If you don't know the hash ID of commit `I`, you'll never find it again.  Git can work *backwards*—given a name `branch` pointing to commit `I`, *Git* can follow the commit-to-parent arrows for you; that's how `git log` works—but Git *can't* work *forwards*.  There are no forward pointing arrows!

#### Clones

Besides the above, Git offers the ability to *clone* a repository.  Here's how clone works:

- You run `git clone` and give it a URL.
- Git makes a *new, totally empty repository:* two databases (for commit and other objects, and for branch and tag and other names), but neither of these has anything in it at all.
- Your Git software saves this URL in the new repository (in an auxiliary "database" that's actually just a simple file like an [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)).
- Your Git software calls up some other Git software, using the URL you provided.  They respond by listing out all their branch and tag and other names, and the hash IDs that go with those.
- Your Git software says "gimme all those objects *and* all their parents and grandparents and everything that makes up the history"—i.e., the full contents of their commits-and-other-objects database.
- They send all that stuff over, and your Git (your software working with your repo) sticks it into your database.
- For each of their *branch* names, your Git software changes those names into your *remote-tracking names*.  Their `main` or `master` becomes your `origin/main` or `origin/master`; their `develop`, if they have one, becomes your `origin/develop`; and so on.

You end up with your two databases being full of stuff:

- You have a full copy of their *objects* database (well, mostly-full: if they have some objects they can't find, due to dropping commits off the end of branches for instance, they don't need to send you those).
- You have *no branch names*.  (Whether you have *branches* depends on what you mean by the word *branch*.)  Instead of *branch* names, you have *remote-tracking names* that start with `origin/`.  *These are how you will find the commits, for now.*

As a final step, your Git now *creates one branch name of your own*.  For instance, if you told `git clone` to `git clone -b develop`, your Git will create your own branch name `develop`.  If you didn't use the `-b` option—and most people don't—your Git asks their Git what name *they recommend*, and creates that name.

In either case, the *commit* your new branch has, as its tip commit, is the *same commit hash ID in their name that on their side is spelled the same way*.  That is, if you let your Git create `main` because they recommend `main`, the commit your `main` has as its *last* commit is the *same* commit that your `origin/main` selects, which is the same commit that *their* `main` selected at the time you ran `git clone`.

By now—it's probably been *seconds*, which on a computer is loads of time—their branch names may select different commits.  But at the time you ran `git clone`, their branch names selected particular commits.  *Your* Git remembers all these, using your repository's *remote-tracking* `origin/*` names.  *Your* repository has *your own* branch names, which you get to create and update however you like, which are different from their branch names, even if you use the same spellings.  That's because their databases are not your databases.

What you and they *share* are the *commits*.  Those are read-only—neither of you can *change* them—and have hash IDs that *every Git in the universe* agrees are the *right* hash IDs, via the hash ID magic.  So your clone of the original (`origin`) repository, and that original repository, are very closely related.  You have your own *branch names*, but you *share the commits*.

#### Fetch and push

Given any *two* repositories—usually, ones that are *related*, although this isn't actually necessary at the start—we can transfer commits from one repository to another:

- The way to *get commits from them* is to use `git fetch`.
- The way to *give commits to them* is to use `git push`.

In both cases, we must give our Git—our software running with our repository—the URL of the other Git (their software and their repository).  If we have a closely-related repository that we made by cloning, we already have the URL, as our Git saved it under the *name* `origin`.  So we just run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and our Git calls up their Git.  They list out their names and hash IDs, and our Git can tell whether we already have some commits—because hash IDs are the true names of objects, and the commits have *unique* hash IDs—or whether we need them.  If we need them, our Git asks for them, which automatically asks for the sender to send the parent hash IDs so that we can see if we have those too.  In this way, we have our Git get, from them, *all the commits they have that we don't*.  We *don't* ask for any of the commits we already have.  Git uses this information to figure out not only which *commits* are new to us, but also which files in those commits are new, and sends us just the new stuff.

Our Git then sticks all the *new* commits and supporting objects into our objects database.  We now have all their commits, plus any we've never given to them.  Then our Git updates our *remote-tracking names* because we know what hash IDs their *branch* names held at the time we ran `git fetch` and we have all those commits, so our Git can update our memory of their branch names.

In fact, this `git fetch` is how the main part of `git clone` works: all `git clone` does is create the empty repository, stash the URL away under the name `origin`, run `git fetch`, and run one final operation to create and check out a branch name.  So if you connect two *unrelated* repositories with `git fetch`, once the fetch is done, the two repositories are now related.

The `git push` command is as close as Git comes to the opposite of `git fetch`.  (**Remember this: `git push`'s opposite is `git fetch`, not `git pull`.**  This was a mistake in naming that Git made early on and we're just stuck with it now.  You just have to memorize it: push/fetch, not push/pull.)  There are a few big differences though:

- With `git fetch`, the action is "get commits and update remote-tracking names".  The default is *all* new-to-us commits and *all* remote-tracking names.
- With `git push`, the action is *send* new commits.  **We must pick which commit our side will start with** to offer them new-to-them commits.  So we run `git push origin somebranch` here, to offer to them any new-to-them commits *we* find with *our branch name `somebranch`*.  We'll start by offering them just the one *tip* commit.  They presumably don't have it, so they'll say "oh yes, send that one", which means we must offer its parent.  If they don't have that they'll ask for it too, which means we offer the grandparent, and so on.  Eventually we get back to some commit that they already have—because we got it from them by cloning—*or* we go all the way back through our history and get to our very first ever commit, that has no parent so we say "that's all there are".

  Once we know which commits are new-to-them, our Git uses its smarts to package up just those commits and the files that are new-to-them as well, and we send over that stuff and they stick it into their repository's objects database.  But now we, or they, have a bit of a dilemma.  How will they *find* these objects?  They are going to need a *name*.

  When we used `git fetch`, we created or updated a *remote-tracking name* to remember the tip commit of one of their *branch* names.  With `git push`, they don't have remote-tracking names for us.  Instead, we ask them—politely by default—to see if they can, please, *create or update one of their **branch** names* to remember our latest commit.

  If `somebranch` is a *new name* to them, they can just create that name.  That won't disturb any of their *existing* names.  So that's easy, they can just say "ok", do it, and we're all good.  But if `somebranch` is one of their *branch* names, what they'll do now is check to make sure we're just *adding commits to their branch*.

Let's go back to our earlier illustration.  Suppose we have these names:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

Let's suppose further that we have *remote-tracking names* that we got *from* `origin` a few seconds, or hours or days, ago:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

We now use `git switch develop` to pick *name* `develop` as our *current branch name:*

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

This trick, of adding the special name `HEAD` to the drawing and "attaching" it to one of the branch names, is how we show which *branch name* we are using in our own Git repository.

Let's make a new commit now, in our Git repository, in the usual way (edit files, `git add`, `git commit`, write a commit message, etc).  We get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I   <-- origin/develop
           \
            J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

We now run `git push origin develop`.  We'll offer them commit `J`, and they will say: *Huh, new hash ID, OK, send me `J`*.  We'll offer them commit `I` next, because that's `J`'s parent.  They'll say *No thanks, already have that one.*  We now know all, or almost all, the commits they have!  They have `I`, but that means they have `H`, which means they have `G`, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit!

So, our Git will package up commit `J` and any new-to-`J` files that aren't duplicates of a file in, say, `H` (maybe we put a file back to the way it was before).  We'll send that over, and then we'll ask them, politely: *Please, if it's OK, set your name `develop` to point to commit `J`* (by commit `J`'s real hash ID of course).

If their `develop`—as represented here by our memory, `origin/develop`—still points to commit `I`, commit `J` *adds on* to their `develop`.  So they'll say *OK, done* to our polite request and we'll know that *their* `develop` now names commit `J`, and our Git will update our picture like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

But suppose that, during these seconds or hours or days, *someone else* added some *other* new commit `K` to *their* `develop`.  That is, *they* have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--K   <-- develop
```

in *their* repository (these are *their* names so we don't have to know or care where their `HEAD` is, and they don't have `J` yet).

We send them a new commit `J`, which they stick in their database:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--K   <-- develop
           \
            J
```

and then we ask them, politely, to please-if-it's-OK move their `develop` to point to `J`.  But this time **it's not OK!**  If they did that, they'd "lose" their commit `K`.  So they will say: *No, if I do that, I will lose something.*  (Git calls this a "non-fast-forward", in Git's usual inscrutable way.)  We'll get an error:

```
 ! [rejected]    develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
```

What we need to do about this error is, usually, *run `git fetch`*, which will get us commit `K`, so that *we* now have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--K   <-- origin/develop
           \
            J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Once we have that, we can decide:

- Is commit `K` good?  Or, should we ask them to throw it away?
- If commit `K` is good, what do we want to do about this?

Our primary choices for "what we want to do" is to use either `git rebase` or `git merge`.  **It's very common to run `git fetch` and then want to run either `git rebase` or `git merge`.**  That's why `git pull` exists: it runs `git fetch`, and then runs either `git rebase` or `git merge`.  The drawbacks to `git pull` are many:

- We don't get to look at commit `K`.  We just *assume* it's good.
- We don't get to look at commit `K` before we decide whether to merge or rebase.
- We don't even know, if we're beginners at Git, that we're doing all of this.
- We don't know what `git merge` and `git rebase` are!
- We don't know what to do when `git merge` or `git rebase` *can't finish*, which happens often enough to matter a lot.
- We don't even know which of `git merge` or `git rebase` we picked!  We *can't* know what to do next because we have no idea what's going on.

So, if you're new to Git, *don't use `git pull`* (yet).  Later, you may want to use it, once you know all this stuff by heart.  I still mostly don't use it myself, and I've been using Git for almost two decades.  I don't *like* `git pull` very much.  (In the last year or so, it's grown a new mode that does what I want, but I'd still rather just run two commands.)

#### Conclusion

Before you worry about whether you should shove another project into a repository (you certainly *can*, but maybe you *shouldn't*, this is a matter of judgement), learn what a repository does for you.  Decide whether you want to map "project" to "repository" one-to-one, or many-to-many, or many-to-one, or one-to-many, or whatever.  There are pluses and minuses to the "monorepo" (everything in one repository) and "polyrepo" (many repositories for one or many projects) approaches.  You won't always get all this right the first time, but be aware that this is what you're doing here.